# ssrs iif syntax

Tags: reporting-services, iif

In my query designer I am trying to use the following query:

```
SELECT        Site, LegalConfigNumber, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM            EPSInfoLive
 iif(@LegalConfigNum  =  0,
WHERE        (InputDate >= @rundate) AND (InputDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, @rundate)),
WHERE        (InputDate >= @rundate) AND (InputDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, @rundate)) AND LegalConfigNumber = @LegalConfigNum)
GROUP BY LegalConfigNumber, Site
ORDER BY Site, LegalConfigNumber
```

When I try to test it, I get a message regarding incorrect syntax by @LegalConfigNum.
I can't seem to find where that would be though.

Comment: Can you even use those expressions in queries? Thought you could only use them in controls like textboxes and such - and you'd need to use `CASE...WHEN` statements and such for queries...

Answer (score 2):

SSRS queries need to be written in SQL. You are mixing SQL and Visual Basic with your use of '@iif'. SQL supports the CASE statement instead of IIF. But you don't need this for what you are showing. The statement below should be logically equivalent:

```
SELECT
   Site,
   LegalConfigNumber,
   COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM
   EPSInfoLive
WHERE
   (InputDate >= @rundate) AND (InputDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, @rundate))
   AND (LegalConfigNumber = @LegalConfigNum OR @LegalConfigNum  =  0)
GROUP BY LegalConfigNumber, Site
ORDER BY Site, LegalConfigNumber
```